# How to track delivery for an outgoing reply message in Twilio?

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am setting up a track delivery status of outgoing messages in NodeJS for a todo list I created on a previous lesson. Now I am instructed to do the following:

1. Add a new route to your web app called "/status"
2. Use the action attribute when you send your reply to a "list" command to subscribe to updates on its delivery at the "/status" URL of your app
3. Be sure to use your app's ngrok URL as Twilio will need the "/status" URL to be publicly accessible
4. Somehow display the delivery status updates as you receive them, either in a UI you build or printing to your terminal
5. You should at least display the MessageSid and the X-Twilio-Signature header on the incoming request
6. Make sure your final status update says your message is "delivered"

I am thinking to incorporate this

```
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages
      .create({
         body: ' ',
         from: '+15017122661',
         statusCallback: '',
         to: '+15558675310'
       })
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

I do also need a /status route but I was not sure how to put them all together and add that into my code below.

my code is the following:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

var itemList = [];

app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
    const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

    const splitContent = req.body.Body.split(' ');

    switch (splitContent[0]) {
        case 'add':
            itemList.push(splitContent.slice(1).join(' ')); // Slice 1 to start at the second item
            twiml.message('Item added');
            break;
        case 'list':
            var result = ''
            var i = 1;
            itemList.forEach(o => {
                result += `${i}. ${o}\n`;
                i++;
            });
            twiml.message(result);
            break;
        case 'remove':
            itemList.splice(splitContent[1] - 1, 1); // Subtract 1 to get the index
            twiml.message('Item removed');
            break;
    }
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
    res.end(twiml.toString());
});

http.createServer(app).listen(1337, () => {
  console.log('Express server listening on port 1337');
});
```

My output needs to update my outgoing reply message, including when it was delivered. I need to make sure I print out the status update on my terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Developer evangelist here.

There are two parts to this problem.

**First** – you have to define the action attribute in your `MessagingResponse`. You can do that like described [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml/message?code-sample=code-messagestatus-reporting-3&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x).

For your code it could look like this for every single response.

```
twiml.message({
    action: '/status',
    method: 'POST'
}, result || 'No items');
```

**Second** – the url or path in the `action` attribute defines an HTTP endpoint which will receive status information about sent messages. In express (the framework you're using) you can define a new route like so.

```
app.post('/status', (req, res) => {
  // log the status information
  console.log(
    req.body.MessageSid,
    req.body.MessageStatus,
    req.headers['x-twilio-signature']
  );
});
```

You can find more information about express and routing in [their documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

I put your example code [on Glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/twilio-message-status-example) (you can easily run node in the cloud there) and adjusted it to your needs. :)

Let me know if that helps. :)

Comment: It’s great to know someone that knows some much about Twilio! Thanks!